# Change directory in PuTTY connection

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, centos, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to a UNIX server with several sites with the same user login. So I use several PuTTY connection with **SSH - Remote command** as

```
cd /var/www/path_to_the_site ; /bin/bash
```

It works fine, besides some CentOS commands are unknown. E.g.:

```
$ service
bash: service: command not found
```

If I've logged in without "remote command", everything is fine, the command exists:

```
$ service
Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
```

What is wrong with "/bin/bash" executing, it can't find some commands?

I use the same login, so I can't just set home directory for user.
E.g. in WinSCP plugin in FAR I can set initial directory for any connection and it works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and belongs to either https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow, as a user. So I missed the difference between different sites. But I'm not a system administrator and use PuTTY as an assist tool for programming sites. Tell me please where tools for programming have to be discussed?  Also I found many question about PuTTY here
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=putty
So I have no chance realize that it's offtopic.
Thank You for proper links for that!

Comment: You got links in the comment by @tink.

Comment: Now I've got the solution from @legoscia

Comment: Goes to show that even people with high reputation counts don't necessarily know the rules around here ;) ...

Comment: Dear @tink! I am a programmer, not linux administrator and I'm not an expert with stackoverflow.com sites. I spend some time for searching https://stackexchange.com/sites# page, but I can find a site where I can ask a question about JavaScript code of my site, that stop working on Chrome browser after updating. I think, experts, like you can mark this question with minus, as it about browser. But I can't find a "Chome.stackexchange.com" dealing with chrome programming problems, as you advice me to ask question dealing with program tools, such as PuTTY ask in unix.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: @SergeyBeloglazov - because others have made the same mistake that you have doesn't mean it's not a mistake. Your question still squarely sits in superuser-space.  I have no idea what chome might be, and why it would deserve a site in its own right. And just because you're a programmer doesn't make executing a shell on a remote machine a programming task. By that logic cooking your breakfast might, too? It can be broken down into sequences; and in feeding you it has, in a way, to do with programming.  Thanks for your persistence, though.

Comment: I can see reasons in your arguments if I know thre is a special site for certain kind of question, But if you don't know that, everything dealing with program and programmers suites for topic, even breakfast might be :)
Ok, so I'm stopping an offtopic. Thank you for giving me an occasion for thinking about structuring an information in tht Internet in the better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `--login` option:

```
cd /var/www/path_to_the_site ; /bin/bash --login
```

That makes bash behave as if it were a login shell, which means that it reads the files `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` - I suspect one of those files sets up the path as needed to invoke `service`.